# how to call function with dynamic name in Daml?

Tags: haskell, daml

the choice call have few function to required to be called based on the values which we passed from list.

For Example:

```
Choice Call: update X
let list = [FunctionX,FunctionZ,FunctionY]
list.forEach (FunctionName =>
  FunctionName  parameter 
)
function 1 :
X:FunctionX parameter  = X
function 2:
Z:FunctionZ parameter  = Z
function3 :
Y:FunctionY parameter  = Y
```

here in this choice expectation is the call function X and function Z how we can achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're after here, but this may be helpful:

```hs
module Main where

import Daml.Script
import qualified DA.Text

data Function = Reverse | Length | Dup
  deriving (Eq, Show)
data Result = ResultInt Int | ResultText Text
  deriving (Eq, Show)

execFn: Text -> Function -> Result
execFn arg = \case
  Reverse -> ResultText (DA.Text.reverse arg)
  Length -> ResultInt (DA.Text.length arg)
  Dup -> ResultText (arg <> arg)

template ChooseYourFunctions
  with
    owner: Party
    argument: Text
  where
    signatory owner
    controller owner can
      RunFunctions: [Result]
        with
          functions: [Function]
        do
          return $ map (execFn argument) functions
           

setup : Script ()
setup = script do
  alice <- allocatePartyWithHint "Alice" (PartyIdHint "Alice")

  exec <- submit alice do
    createCmd ChooseYourFunctions with
      owner = alice
      argument = "hello"
  
  result <- submit alice do
    exerciseCmd exec RunFunctions with functions = [Reverse, Length, Reverse, Reverse, Dup]

  debug result

  return ()
```

This will print out the following trace (from the `debug` call):

```
[ResultText "olleh",ResultInt 5,ResultText "olleh",ResultText "olleh",ResultText "hellohello"]
```

where you can see that we're calling the list of functions supplied.

If you want more flexibility in defining the functions on a per-call basis, you may want to have a look at these [two](https://discuss.daml.com/t/functions-in-data-structure/1417) [threads](https://discuss.daml.com/t/encoding-inequalities-in-an-adt/1620) on the Daml forum.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is probably to just add a parameter to the choice and make it change its behavior based on the input.